# Who's the ginger Eddie being referenced in the Bronn scene?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones S08E01 Winterfell*, when Bronn is in a brothel, one of the girls recalls a ginger Eddie

> Girl 1: That boy Eddie...
>   Girl 2: The ginger?
>   Girl 1: That's him. Came back with his face burnt right off. He's got no eyelids now.

I saw a facebook post where some fan claimed that this ginger Eddie is referencing Ed Sheeran, who was in S07E01. He was a Lannister soldier, in the Twins area. Daenerys later attacks Lannister soldiers with her Dragons in S07E04.

Is there any official confirmation that this ginger Eddie is actually Ed Sheeran?

Comment: *Some dead man!* (-- The Mountain, 4x08)

Answer (score 10):

There is no confirmation, but this does seem very likely.

One of the things we do know for sure is that Sheeran's Character was called Ed.

> Sheeran does have red hair, and as [per the season seven scripts](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/12/game-of-thrones-scripts-secrets-cersei-pregnancy-tyrion-daenerys-snow-on-the-throne), his character's name was Ed.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>['Game of Thrones' may have revealed a terrible fate for Ed Sheeran's character - Insider](https://www.thisisinsider.com/game-of-thrones-season-eight-premiere-may-reveal-fate-ed-sheeran-character-2019-4)</sub>

HBO representative's refuse to comment.

> An HBO representative declined to confirm the reference to INSIDER. "As usual, we don't comment on storyline. Sorry," they said.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>['Game of Thrones' may have revealed a terrible fate for Ed Sheeran's character - Insider](https://www.thisisinsider.com/game-of-thrones-season-eight-premiere-may-reveal-fate-ed-sheeran-character-2019-4)</sub>

It's likely he's dead because of the fans' negative reaction to his cameo which even he awknoledged.

> "No one wants to see me come back," Sheeran told MTV. "I wanted to be a cameo in it, and I've done the cameo. I'm cool with it, though. I enjoyed it."
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Ed Sheeran says his 'Game of Thrones' character is probably dead: 'No one wants to see me come back'](https://www.thisisinsider.com/game-of-thrones-ed-sheeran-cameo-soldier-dead-2017-9)</sub>

**TL;DR**: There has been no *official* confirmation.

Comment: I'd like to add that Ed Sheeran himself believes it's him because he had posted this as instagram story https://i.iheart.com/v3/re/new_assets/5cb4ba4b25ed2689549222f2